# MySQL how to Retrieve data that associate with multiple value

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I need to retrieve the `DepartmentID` for departments that currently have two open courses.

I have `Course(CourseID, CreditHours, DeptID)`

How can I retreive DeptIDs with 2 different CourseIDs?

Example

| CourseID | CreditHours | DeptID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 |  | 001 |
| 002 |  | 001 |
| 003 |  | 002 |

```
Select DeptID
From Course
Where ???
```

Comment: Hint: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CourseID) > 1`

Comment: Please show what you tried. This sounds like homework, we're not going to do it for you.